# AlertDialog example giving errors

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I'm new to Java/ Android development (I started learning last night) so it is entirely possible I'm doing something horrendously stupid. However, after more than an hour Googling I've come up with nothing. I'm using Eclipse as my editor.

I'm reading the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for `AlertDialog`, which gives an example:

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            ((FragmentAlertDialog)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

I originally re-wrote it so I can start committing some of the methods to memory, but got an error *"FragmentAlertDialog cannot be resolved to a type"*. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to make sure I had the proper imports, but still it didn't go away.

So I copied/ pasted the example code and did the following, in this order:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to get the imports right (using `android.app.DialogFragment`, not `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`)
2. Declared my package at the top
3. Replaced `R.string.alert_dialog_ok` and `R.string.alert_dialog_cancel` with `android.R.string.ok` and `android.R.string.cancel` respectively
4. Removed `setIcon()`, as I don't have an icon to put in yet

I'm still getting errors:

1. `FragmentAlertDialog` cannot be resolved to a type (x4)
2. Illegal modifier for the class `MyAlertDialogFragment`; only `public`, `abstract` & `final` are permitted

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something wrong with the example code?

Comment: whether this is separate class or inner class of FragmentAlertDialog?

Comment: Can you update this with your solution? I am stuck here too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.FragmentAlertDialog

Make sure the Activity you want to cast to is named `FragmentAlertDialog`. Make sure to also save everything - sometimes Eclipse won't make the connection until everything is saved.

> 2.Illegal modifier for the class MyAlertDialogFragment; only public, abstract & final are permitted

Take out the `static` modifier:

```
public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
```

or keep `static` and  move this Fragment so it is enclosed within the Activity you want. This means that `MyAlertDialogFragment` should be inside your Activity, *before* that Activity's closing brace.

> I'm new to Java/Android development

Don't start off with something so complicated. Learn [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) then move to [Android.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I did originally take out the static, but I figured it was there for a reason.

As for having an Activity of 'FragmentAlertDialog' - I do not have such an activity. That'll be why. Nowhere in the docs (at least, not that I saw) did it mention it.

Comment: @Aeisor If you do make the FragmentAlertDialog Activity, make sure to have the `doPositiveClick()` and `doNegativeClick()` methods and make sure your Fragment only attaches to that Activity. Also, a good tutorial to follow for fragments is [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Comment: As this is to create a one-size-fits-all Message Dialog (ie- "You've completed an action! Well done, now click OK") I've removed the need for the activity.

The doPositiveClick method will be declared inside the same, generic class to simply close the dialog. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi try these code to implement alert dialog

```
       AlertDialog.Builder alert2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
            alert2.setTitle("Your Title");
            alert2.setMessage("Your Messages");
            final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
            input2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
            alert2.setView(input2);
            alert2.setPositiveButton(GButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Do something with value!                 
                    try
                    {
                    // do your stuff here   
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                } 
            });

            alert2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                }
            });

            alert2.show();
```

Comment: I tried a variety of the other answers out there that looked similar, but I kept getting an exception on the Builder instantiation.  This solution did the trick though - thank you much for the solution and complete source here.